# Passing multiple backslashes in function argument not working

Tags: php, parameter-passing, backslash

This

`echo date('g:iA \o\n D, M jS', strtotime('2018-02-23 07:42:22'));`

echoes this

`7:42AM on Fri, Feb 23rd`

but this

```
function dateformat($source, $format = "Y-m-d")
{
    if(empty($source) || $source == '0000-00-00') return false;
    $date = date($format, strtotime($source));
    if(date('Y', strtotime($date)) == '1969' && strpos($source, '1969') === false) return false;
    if(date('Y', strtotime($date)) == '1970' && strpos($source, '1970') === false) return false;
    return $date;
}
echo dateformat('2018-02-23 07:42:22', 'g:iA \o\n D, M jS');
```

echoes this

While this

`echo dateformat('2018-02-23 07:42:22', "g:iA \o\n D, M jS");`

echoes this

`7:42AM o Fri, Feb 23rd`

In other words, with single quotes, I get a return value of `false`. With double quotes, the function argument passes the `\o` correctly, but not the `\n`.

All sorts of different tests yield unpredictable results. I thought it had to do with `\n` being reserved, so I tried `\o\o` just to test. That returned `false`, while `\o\n` passed the `\o` successfully.

I've been using this function for years this way, and just now noticed the issue, so I thought perhaps it might have to do with my recent switch from `Dreamweaver` to `Visual Studio Code`, but I took these tests over to [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) and got the same results, so it's not a code editor issue.

If there's not a solution (which would be my first preference), is there at least an explanation as to what is causing this behavior?

*UPDATE*: To sum up the major problem, I can't pass more than one backslashed character to the function's argument. It will return false if I do. But anything I want to do works fine in the native php date function.

Comment: Maybe `\n` has some sort of special meaning?

Comment: No, I already addressed that.

Comment: See OP re: `\o\o` test.

Comment: You addressed injecting a newline into your string and then trying to run it through `strtotime`?

Comment: I'm not running _anything_ here through `strtotime`.

Comment: If you notice, the issue revolves around the `format` argument, not the `source` argument.

Comment: In one instance yes, but in `$date = date($format, strtotime($source));` and `if(date('Y', strtotime($date))` you are returning `false`.  You are doing to much, just use `date` and or `datetime` class.

Comment: You're not paying close enough attention. Thanks for your attempts to help.

Comment: And again for clarity, my question revolves around the `$format` argument. Not once, anywhere, do I pass my `$format` variable through `strtotime`.

Comment: `var_dump($date);exit;` after the second line of your function.  You'll see that it works just fine.  It's because you're remove the year context in your `date()` call and then running `strtotime()` on the result.  Also, please stop being so dismissive of those trying to help you.  Any time someone says that they are dead sure that a problem is _not_ somewhere, 9 times out of 10, guess where the problem is?

Comment: Gotchya. Thanks. It's the "on" in the date string that is causing it to return false. Appreciated.

Comment: The solution that I need is to do this:

`if(date('Y', strtotime($source)) == '1969' && strpos($source, '1969') === false) return false;` etc.

Comment: Changing $date to $source on the 1969 and 1970 lines.

Comment: So, this was just another case where the magic of `strtotime` wasn't being magical enough :)

Comment: Turns out, yes. AbraCadaver was saying that I was passing a `newline` into `strtotime`. I was not. The problem, it turns out, was that I was passing the word "on" into `strtotime`.

Comment: When you used the double quoted format string you _were_ passing a newline into strtotime. After you used that format string to produce `$date`, `$date` would have contained a newline, and `$date` gets passed to strtotime in the subsequent lines.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I see I was wrong, and was too quickly dismissive. But in fact, in my actual code, I'm only using single quotes. The double quote was created just for test purposes for this SO question.

Answer (score 2):

For the single-quoted string the escaped characters are literal `\o\n` and this, returns `false`, so does your function:

```
$date = date($format, strtotime($source));
```

For the double quoted string the characters are escaped, however `\n` is the escape sequence for a *newline* and so you get a newline not `n`.  Do a view source on the page and you will see:

```
7:42AM o
 Fri, Feb 23rd
```

To correct this use a double escape:

```
"g:iA \o\\n D, M jS"
```

Comment: Thanks. You were right all along. But the actual solution I need is to not pass the word "on" to the third and fourth lines of my function. So I need to change $date to $source on those lines. So if you want to update your answer I will mark it correct.

Comment: The reason being, I'm not actually using double quotes in my code. That was something I did for the SO question to show different results when I started testing.